# Ruby on Railsのバッチ処理にてモデルを読み込めない事象に関して

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Railsにて、Web APIを定期的に実行し、データを加工、DBにインサートする処理を実装しようと思っているのですが、
下に記載されている原因不明のエラーでモデルの呼び出しができない状態です。

lib/tasks/repository.rake

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

namespace :repository do
  desc "get repositories list and delete old repositories list at 11:00 every day"
  task :get_repositories do
    save_repositories
    delete_repositories
  end

  def save_repositories
    languages.each do |language|

      uri =
          URI.parse("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:#{language}&sort=stars&order=desc")
      https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      https.use_ssl = true
      response = https.start {
        https.get(uri.request_uri)
      }

      if response.code == '200'
        results = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode response.body
        results["items"].each do |repository|
          Repository.create(name: repository["name"], language: repository["language"],
                            url: repository["html_url"], scores: repository["score"], issues: repository["issues"])
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def delete_repository
    puts "Hello World"
  end

  def languages
    ["Javascript", "Ruby", "Python", "Java", "Go"]
  end
end
```

app/models/repository.rb

```
class Repository < ApplicationRecord

end
```

エラー内容：

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Repository
```

もし情報が不足していましたらお手数ですがコメントをお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

```
task get_repositories: :environment do
  hogehoge
end
```

のように、 environment を依存タスクとして指定してやると、解決するような気がします。